# How do I coalesce data from various sources?

Tags: dataset

How do I setup an environment where I can coalesce data from various sources, like mysql databases and csv files, on my macbook? Is there some opensource tool like informatica? or... ?

Comment: If you can live without a GUI: http://pandas.pydata.org/ and http://odo.pydata.org/

Comment: Agreed, I typically use pandas as "glue" in ad hoc situations. If I need something more permanent I might build a small database and write some scripts to load the data into that, or in your case you have a mysql database so if I have write permissions I might just build a table and load the csv files into that db. If it is a one-off, pandas is really the way to go (if you're comfortable with python).

Answer (score 0):

Options include:

- Do it in your code like @Emre said. Pandas (if you're using Python)
  has lots of options for joining and unioning data sets. If you are using R, look up dataframe operations.
- Create yourself a small "data mart" or "data lake" in a DB like PostgreSQL or MySQL whose sole purpose is to coalesce things. This is what I typically do, because databases can handle way more data than you could fit in memory and SQL is very good at filtering, joining, and subsetting. Some people may use an ETL took like Informatica (which is neither open source nor cheap) but it is generally not necessary for ad-hoc analysis.